# React-Native-Maps unable to set "title" property

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

For my MapMarker I don't want an image, I want text (a bldg number I assign).  Any suggestions???  In the Google API docs, and in the Native Code, I can see a Title property that's defined as a "string".  However, when setting a prop "title" to a value in MapMarker it never shows up on the Map.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is developer a text custom marker, you could try:

```
    <MapView.Marker  coordinate={marker.coordenates}>
        <View style={styles.markerContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                write the text
            </Text>
        </View>
    </MapView.Marker>
```

Comment: thanks!  That did work!  I was surprised it was actually "title" as a prop - works now!